# Visual Studio Code : Flip 'Split EditorTabs(groups)' view, 'LEFT to RIGHT' or 'RIGHT to LEFT'

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have two split views open on the 'Left view' and 'Right view'.
both views contain different tabs, for instance, the 'Left view' has two files(A.txt, B.txt) open, and the 'Right view' has three files(X.txt, Y.txt, Z.txt) open.

Is there any way to swap the groups of files present on the 'Left view' and 'Right view'? In this example,

(A.txt, B.txt) moves to the 'Right view' and files(X.txt, Y.txt, Z.txt) move to the 'Left view'.

Comment: Look at the `View: Move Editor Group Right` or left commands to swap two editor groups.

Comment: @Mark, No command is present under the menu's view section.

Comment: It is confusingly named `View: Move Editor Group Right` but it is in the Command Palette, that is why I mentioned commands.   It isn't under the `view` menu, sorry.

Comment: @Mark, I am able to find it under the command pallet, and it's working as expected. Thanks for the suggestion. Please put this in answers and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 groups an easy to swap them left<->right is to move the left one to the right (or vice versa) using the command (found in the Command Palette)

```
View: Move Editor Group Right
```

if focus is somewhere in the left editor group.  That command is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> by default.

Or use the `Move Editor Group Left` if the focus is in the right group to start with.